# Incomplete response from webservice C# SoapClient

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, invalid-characters

My software use a `'Service Reference'`, auto generated to deal with a 3party SOAP webservice.
The service has a method that return a response with a single string property

This string has some data with ';' separators, include a XML text with business data.

In some responses i note a incomplete response text it always end on a some like this.

```
um prejuízo ao hospital.&#xd
```

The **&#xd** seams br the problem.

Well a try to execute the same method on WCF Test and SoapUI and for my surprise, the response is complete and correct.

Search on the web a found some material about this characters, is a illegal, but not to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you try to configure the encoding inside the binding with the "textMessageEncoding" element?

Comment: No, i didnt know about this configuration tag. I will try a send feedback´. Tnkz

Comment: I change te from **textEncoding="utf-8"** to **textEncoding="UNicode"** and works for me.

Comment: thats good. I will put like an answer to that you accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the encoding inside the binding with the "textMessageEncoding" element.